# Having troubles with creating Hash in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]

I am new in RoR. I am trying to create a Hash on Rails Console but having these errors. I am using PostgreSql Database. Plz give me any solution.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: where's the `Hash`?

Comment: Can you post the `Catelogue` model code in the question?(no pictures please)

Comment: Do you have **name** column in your **Catelogue** model?

Comment: class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :catelogue, optional:true
end

Comment: Please post your Catelogue class. Because the error comes from there. You have an argument error, so the issue is, that the initialize method does not accept the arguments you are giving to it. Also please don't post pictures, but put the actual error message in a codeblock.

Comment: class Catelogue < ApplicationRecord
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :posts
end

Answer (score 1):

```
rails c
User.new
field(name="nil")
User.create(name="hi")
```

user is the modelname